# Dynamically retriving the compiling datetime of a python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-import

I have a python app that can dynamically import external modules. Basically, at a certain point I run this code:

```
dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name]=__import__ (app_module_name)
```

Since those are webapps, the user can modify the source code of a module and try to reload it.
Reloading it can have no success if the module have an error, and in this case, Python takes the last version of it. So I have something like:

```
try:
    dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name]=imp.reload(app_module_name) 
except:
    ...
```

is there a way to *automatically* know when a module as been succesfully imported?

I wonder if exists a property of this kind:

```
print ('last imported time',dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name].__compile_date_time__)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such metadata stored with the imported module, no.

To prevent Python from *reusing* the already imported module on failure, remove it from `sys.modules` first:

```
existing = sys.modules.pop(app_module_name, None)

try:
    dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name] = importlib.import_module(app_module_name) 
except Exception:
    if existing is None:
        # we had successfully imported this before.
```

Alternatively, add a date yourself:

```
try:
    dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name] = imp.reload(app_module_name)
    dynamic_imported_modules[app_module_name].__imported__ = datetime.datetime.now()
except Exception:
    # ...
```

and consult that value; on reload the extra global will be preserved.